# how to save the text in the web page in readable format

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, html

I have a web page for example ([http://guyism.com/humor/mathematical-equations-that-explain-men.htm](http://guyism.com/humor/mathematical-equations-that-explain-men.html)l). Using `HttpWebRequest` I can get the stream of the webpage.
Now I want to display the content (see image) back to browser like the below image. How can achieve this.

[image]

Comment: Is this a page on your server, or are you trying to display content you don't control?  It can make a differences in the approach.

Comment: can you show the way you are getting the remote page stream using HttpWebRequest? do you want to simply render that content inside a div in your page?

Comment: Also, is the page you are trying to access...does it require a login?

Comment: A div won't work, because he needs linked in files to load, like css, javascript, etc...Also, he wants in an image format, which means there will need to be some translation / rendering done at some point.

Comment: I dont have control on the content. It could be random pages.

Comment: I want to do it C# code behind.

Comment: Can you explain at a high level what you are attempting to accomplish with this setup?  Some solutions might not be acceptable depending on what you are trying to acheive.  For instance, is this being done in a batch (like on a server) where it won't matter what appears on the screen?  Is it for an end user application?

Comment: That is going to be difficult.  What you need is something that will translate an arbitrary html page into an image.  I don't think .net ships with any libraries that will help you with that.  You may have to look for a third party library that can do that (especially in realtime [ie. not batched])

Comment: I think am recreating a webpage but i am excluding unwanted data and reapplying different style on the page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3642/discussion-between-praneeth-and-wllmsaccnt)

Comment: Does it have to be an image?  Or can it just be displayed on the resulting page?  If so, you may want to look into IFrames

Answer (score 0):

Using an iframe can be one solution to your issue depending on what you are looking for. An alternative if you want to grab pages and spit them back out is using cURL. It can also provide similar functionality. There are a few web proxies built off of it. Here is some information on both.

iframes:

http://www.iframehtml.com/

cURL:
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html

cURL for .Net
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/dotnet/

Answer (score 0):

How about this, using the WebBrowser control. However it depends on the structure of guyism.com, so for random pages you can do a lookup of the container divs (??)

```
        void Load()
        {
            string html = DownloadHtml( "http://guyism.com/humor/mathematical-equations-that-explain-men.html" );

            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches( html, @"(<div class=""blog-post-inside"">.*?<center>---</center>)", RegexOptions.Singleline );    

            webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;

            webBrowser.DocumentText = matches[ 0 ].Groups[ 1 ].Value;
        }

        string DownloadHtml( string url )
        {
            using ( var client = new WebClient() )
            {
                using ( var reader = new StreamReader( client.OpenRead( url ) ) )
                {
                    return reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
```